# Populating a hidden form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, handlebars.js, mustache

The GET operation on my application returns the data in an array:

```
Value":[{"Id":"6b7","Notes":"testing","CreatedBy":"User1"},{"Id":"6b7","Notes":"Testing 1","CreatedBy":"User2"}]
```

I use the above to populate a template:

```
<div class="create-note">
    <form>
        **<input type="hidden" id="Id" name="Id" value="{{this.Value.Id}}" />**       

        <textarea id="Notes" name="Notes"></textarea>       
        <button for="" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary ">Add Note</button>
        <button type="reset" class="btn">Cancel</button>
    </form>
            {{#unless this.Value.length}}
    <div class="alert alert-info">Notes do not exist.</div>
{{else}}
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>                        
            <th style="text-align:left">Note</th>
            <th style="text-align:left">Created By</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {{#each this.Value}}
            <tr>                
                <td>
                    {{this.Notes}}
                </td>
                <td>
                    {{this.CreatedBy}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
{{/unless}}
</div>
```

How do I populate the hidden form field (Id). value={{this.Value.Id}} doesn't work because we have an array.

Comment: Can you do something like `this.Value[index].id` ? Although I find it kind of interesting that each object in the array, despite seeming to be a different object has the same Id.

Comment: That is how the data is. The Id is same for all records and the other fields vary.

Comment: this.Value[index].id throws an error

Comment: What kind of error is it throwing?

Comment: Error: Parse error on line 3:
...gnId" value="{{this.Value[0].Id}
-----------------------^
Expecting 'ID'

Comment: Do you think the double quote **Value":** between your property name and colon `Value":[{"Id":"6b7",` is the problem? (Or maybe lacking one before Value...) I thought maybe it was just a typo in your question but if it's in your code that might be causing the parse error. Just checking that first.

Comment: no. I just copied the o/p from firebug. So missed out on the closing ""

Comment: I guess the only other thing I can say is, is your template actually receiving the `this.Value` data at all? For example, if you `fetch()` the data and `render()`, but the `fetch()` being async hasn't loaded the data yet... then Id would be missing. A good test might be to get rid of that line and see if the `{{this.Value.length}}` is working and what you expect. Other than that I'm out of ideas. :-)

Comment: Yes. {{this.Value.length}} gets the correct data :)

Answer (score 2):

Pull the `Id` out in JavaScript and put it where you want it:

```
var data = {
    "Value": [
        {"Id": "6b7", "Notes": "testing", "CreatedBy": "User1"},
        {"Id": "6b7", "Notes": "Testing 1", "CreatedBy": "User2"}
    ]
};
data.Id = data.Value[0].Id;

var tmpl = Handlebars.compile($('#template').html());
var html = tmpl(data);
```

And then refer to `{{this.Id}}` (or just `{{Id}}`) in your template.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/WSAxn/

Alternatively, add a helper that can dig the value out but that's seems like unnecessary complexity.

You have to get used to massaging your data into a Handlebars-friendly form if you're going to use Handlebars. The simplicity of Handlebars has both advantages and drawbacks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am very new to Handlebars - how exactly do I achieve the above?