# How do you populate a hidden div using handlebars data?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, handlebars.js

The handlebars data shows up fine on the static page, but the problem is I also have a modal, and the data is not being populated correctly on the modal.

I am using the avgrund modal [(you can view the Codepen here)](https://codepen.io/hakimel/pen/wFfGs)

## main.js - handlebars code

```
var projectData = [
    {
        id: "0",
        name: "Jack",
    },
    {
        id: "1",
        name: "Sally",
    },
];
var theTemplateScript = $("#project-template").html();
var theTemplate = Handlebars.compile(theTemplateScript);
$("#content").append(theTemplate(projectData));
```

## index.html

```
<div id="content">
<script id="project-template" type="x-handlebars-template">

    <div class="pile">
      {{#each this}}

        <a onclick="avgrund.activate( 'stack' );">

          <div class="box box{{id}}">
              <span class="project_name project_name{{id}}">{{name}}</span>
          </div>

        </a>



          <aside class="avgrund-popup">
            <h2>{{name}}</h2>
            <p>
           You can hit ESC or click outside to close the modal. Give it a go to see the reverse transition.
            </p>
          </aside>
      {{/each}}
    </div>
  </script>
</div>
```

### Problem

The div boxes will show up fine, but whenever I click the boxes so that the modal appears, the modal only displays the last element in `projectData`.

I've been able to have the data appear fine when I use bootstrap modals, but for some reason not the avgrund modal.

## Hint at a possible solution?

I think the answer to [this StackOverflow q: how to populate hidden form field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520939/populating-a-hidden-form-field) hints as something that might work, e.g. pulling out the data and re-inserting it in the avgrund modal code, as such

```
var data = {
"Value": [
    {"Id": "6b7", "Notes": "testing", "CreatedBy": "User1"},
    {"Id": "6b7", "Notes": "Testing 1", "CreatedBy": "User2"}
]};
data.Id = data.Value[0].Id;
var tmpl = Handlebars.compile($('#template').html());
var html = tmpl(data);
```

But I don't fully understand the answer and wasn't able to get it to work. Could someone point to some approaches or guiding principles that might be helpful?

Comment: Are you sure your HTML tags are in balance? It looks like there's an extra `</div>`. Something like that can screw up a template.

Comment: just doublechecked- divs are OK. It's from other divs that I forgot to fuly erase when I was trying to simplify the code for this question. Thanks for the catch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fiddle that shows a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/9f9w1trs/

As pointed out by Roamer-1888 you had an extra closing `</div>` in there. You didn't include the code that actually compiles the template and populates it.

The basic idea is that you define a template - like you did

```
<script id="project-template" type="x-handlebars-template"> ....</script>
```

Then you "compile" the template (you can pre-compile them for performance reasons or if you'd like to only use the lightweight run-time library opposed to the full library).

```
var source = $("#project-template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
```

and then you can populate your template with data ...

```
var populatedHtml = template(projectData);
```

and finally you add your populated HTML to the DOM

```
$('#myContent').append(populatedHtml);
```

Handlebars doesn't really care if you add it to a hidden div or not - it just replaces contents between {{}} ;)

Comment: Thanks for the helpful jsfiddle!
If you click "Jack", does the modal say "Sally"?

Comment: Ha - yes it does! The problem is that both pop-ups get created - and the both have the same class assigned (avgrund-popup) - so they both get shown on button click - and "sally" has a higher z-index than "jack" as the div is created later - so she shows - when you hide them you can see 'jack' fade out!

Comment: Maybe Jack is a cross-dresser!

Comment: Looks like there is a flavor of Avgrund that supports calling modals by id: https://github.com/hakimel/Avgrund/blob/master/js/avgrund.js this should help.
But I do like @Roamer-1888's argument much better than my boring explanation